# PHP Array of Objects :: Cannot use object of type <MyObject> as array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a class represents a table in database
I want to fill the table into array of objectsas following:

```
$subCat = array();
$count=0;
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $subCatName = $line["sub_cat_name"];
    $subCatShortDescription = $line["short_description"];
    $subCatLongDescription = $line["long_description"];
    $subCat = new SubCat($countryId, $catName, $subCatShortDescription, $subCatLongDescription);
    $subCat[$count++] = $subCat;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type SubCat as array in C:\AppServ\www\MyWebSite\classes\SubCat.php on line 34
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code is somewhat confusing because first you define `$subcat` as an empty array and then you create it as some sort of object with `new Subcat`. Then, you try to use is as an array again. That's what PHP is complaining about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using your object as an array:

```
$subCat = array():
// ... code
$subCat = new SubCat($countryId, $catName, $subCatShortDescription, $subCatLongDescription);
$subCat[$count++] = $subCat;
```

When you assign the new object to `$subCat` it's no longer an array, so `$subCat[$index]`.

Instead use something like:

```
$subCat = array();
// ... code
$subCat[$count++] = new SubCat($countryId, $catName, $subCatShortDescription, $subCatLongDescription);
```

Comment: actually you don't need an increment at all, just declare the array container outside on top of the while loop and just normally push the newly created object inside the loop: `$subcat[] = new SubCat`.

Comment: Certainly the count is not necessary. I just kept it to reply with the least changes.